# Error #1006: value is not a function

Tags: flash, flash-cs3

`//Create the URLLOader instance
    var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();`

```
//the data will come as URL-encoded variables
myLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES

//Load using an URLRequest, even beeing local
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("flash/index.php"))

//onLoad handler listener
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDataLoad)

//add a listener for the complete event
function onDataLoad(evt:Event){
    for(var i:uint=0; i<evt.target.data.cant; i++){
            var mc_holder:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
                mc_holder.name = "mc_holder"+i;
                mc_holder.x = 30;
                mc_holder.y = mc_holder.height+10;
                //trace(mc_holder.y = mc_holder.height*i)
                addChild(mc_holder);
        var loader:Loader = new Loader()

        loader.load(new URLRequest(evt.target.data["Image"+i]))
           mc_holder.addChild(loader)
        mc_holder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);

        function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
            var my_thumb = e.target.name;
            trace(my_thumb);
            my_thumb.startDrag();

            }
```

This gives me error Error #1006: value is not a function. when i click on drag

Answer (score 0):

You posted code seems to have syntactical errors, but I think the solution for your problem should be the call of `e.target.startDrag();`. With your call of `my_thumb.startDrag();` you are trying to call a function `startDrag` on `e.target.name` which doesn't exists.

Alternativly you can replace

```
var my_thumb = e.target.name;
```

with

```
var my_thumb = e.target;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors in your code. You're also trying to do too much with one single method. You parse your data, create a movie clip , add a loader , load an image then call a function on the loader... I've tried to get rid of the obvious mistakes , but there's no doubt your code could be improved by separating concerns.

If you split your code into separate methods, your code will be more flexible & much easier to debug too... You could load & parse your variables , in another function prepare your XML data for your designs , then leave the display logic to another method.

In the meantime, here's your code with less mistakes

```
    function onDataLoad(evt:Event)
    {

        for(var i:uint=0; i< evt.target.data.cant; i++)
        {
            var mc_holder:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            mc_holder.name = "mc_holder"+i;
            mc_holder.x = 30;
            mc_holder.y = mc_holder.height+10;

             //trace(mc_holder.y = mc_holder.height*i);
            addChild(mc_holder);

            var loader:Loader = new Loader();

            loader.load(new URLRequest(evt.target.data["Image"+i]));

            mc_holder.addChild(loader)
            mc_holder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);

        }
    }

    function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        var my_thumb:MovieClip = e.target as MovieClip;
        trace(my_thumb);
        my_thumb.startDrag();

    }
```